# KMail with akonadi-ews forgets password

Tags: ms-exchange, kmail, kwallet, akonadi

I'd like to use Kontact/Kmail with our Exchange-Server. I am using Thunderbird with ExQuilla right now, so I am sure, my settings are working. On configuring the exchange server, the connection test button works without error. But if I apply the settings, the connection does not work.

After searching for the issue, I found a bug which seems to fit on what I am experiencing:

- https://github.com/KrissN/akonadi-ews/issues/48
- https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=393002

But on the github issue, there is a workaround mentioned, which other users implemented with success. I can confirm, that in KWallet, the password is not stored. But I could not reproduce the workaround.

Perhaps, somebody could give a better explanation how to implement this workaround to make Kmail work with Exchange? How to find the right resource in KWallet or set the password with a DBUS function? Or is there another way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some experimentation I could  implement the workaround.

If you create a new Exchange account, the resource name is the default name for the account. If not, you can use the akonadiconsole to retrieve the resource name:

[image]

With the resource name, you can add a password entry in kwallet for "akonadi-ews" using the resource name and append "rc". For example a resource "akonadi_ews_resource_0" gets an entry "akonadi_ews_resource_0rc":

[image]

If you create a password like this, it is saved and used by KMail/Kontact.

(Sorry for the german locale in the screenshots, I hope the intention is clear.)

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day!

Comment: god bless you, man